# Trouble returning web scraping output as python dictionary

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I am attempting to scrape a website of its staff roster (https://www.milb.com/greenville/ballpark/frontoffice) and I want the end product to be a dictionary in the format of {staff: position}. I am currently stuck with it returning every staff name and position as a separate string. It is hard to clearly post the output, but it essentially goes down the list of names, then the position. So for example the first name on the list is to be paired with the first position, and so on. The lowest I could get to the text I need by using the `class_` parameter was the individual `div` that the `p` is contained in. I am pretty sure that the way to accomplish this would be to use `zip` to put the elements in a dictionary, but I have tried several ways of getting there and nothing has worked so far. I am still inexperienced with python and new to web scraping, but I am relativity well versed with html and css, so help would be greatly appreciated.

````py
# Simple script attempting to scrape 
# the staff roster off of the 
# Greenville Drive website

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.milb.com/greenville/ballpark/frontoffice'

page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

staff = soup.find_all('div', class_='l-grid__col l-grid__col--xs-12 l-grid__col--sm-4 l-grid__col--md-3 l-grid__col--lg-3 l-grid__col--xl-3')

for staff in staff:
    data = staff.find('p')
    if data:
        print(data.text.strip())

position = soup.find_all('div', class_='l-grid__col l-grid__col--xs-12 l-grid__col--sm-4 l-grid__col--md-6 l-grid__col--lg-6 l-grid__col--xl-6')

for position in position:
    data = position.find('p')
    if data:
        print(data.text.strip())  

# This code so far provides the needed data, but need it in a dict()
```
````